# Power bi - Getting the most recent value from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

Hi I'm a beginner in Power bi

[image]

I have two tables
Table 1 has Dates, Unique IDs and Emails

Table 2 has list of Unique IDs same as the ones in table 1

Using DAX, I want to add a calculated column to the 2nd table  to get the most recent email from table 1 based on the unique id and also avoid Email Values

Thank you.

Comment: You can create relationships between tables, and then use RELATED function to add column in Table 1. Its possible to use LOOKUPVALUE to achieve, but it can affect performance on large tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`with DAX measure - if both tables have a relationship`**

```
Measure1 = 
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Email] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table 1',
        'Table 1'[Date]
            = CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'Table 1'[Date] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Unique_ID] )
            )
    )
)
```

**`with DAX calculated column - if both tables have a relationship`**

```
Column1 =
CALCULATE (
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table 1'[Email] ),
        FILTER (
            'Table 1',
            'Table 1'[Date]
                = CALCULATE (
                    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Date] ),
                    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Unique_ID] )
                )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

**`with DAX measure - if both tables have no relationship`**

```
Measure2 =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Email] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table 1',
        'Table 1'[Date]
            = CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'Table 1'[Date] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Unique_ID] )
            )
    ),
    TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Table 2'[Unique_ID] ), 'Table 1'[Unique_ID] )
)
```

**`with DAX calculated column - if both tables have no relationship`**

```
Column2 = 
CALCULATE (
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table 1'[Email] ),
        FILTER (
            'Table 1',
            'Table 1'[Date]
                = CALCULATE (
                    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Date] ),
                    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Unique_ID] )
                )
        ),
        TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Table 2'[Unique_ID] ), 'Table 1'[Unique_ID] )
    )
)
```

[image: s3]

[image: s4]

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry I just realized you're already having a table2. Now I've split the answer in two party. New Column and New Table.

---

**Creating NEW COLUMN**

In this case you could try:

```
Most_Recent_Mail = SELECTCOLUMNS(TOPN(1,FILTER(table1, table1[Unique_ID] = table1[Unique_ID]), table1[Date]), "mail", Tabelle1[mail])
```

---

**Creating NEW TABLE**

I copied your table:

[image]

Now we can create a new table:

[image]

And use the following DAX code to fill this table:

```
New_Table = SUMMARIZE(table1,table1[Unique_ID], "Most_Recent_Mail", 
            CALCULATE(VALUES(table1[mail]), FILTER(all(table1), table1[Date] = max(table1[Date]))))
```

- [SUMMARIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax) is like a group function.
- With [CALCULCATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) you can create expressions in a filtered context.
- With [FILTER](http://FILTER) you can create a new context/subset.
- [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) is ignoring all existing filters an returns the full dataset.

**Result:**

[image]

**PS:** Just to understand. If you only wanted the date, the formula would be much shorter

```
table2 = SUMMARIZE(table1,table1[Unique_ID], "Max_Date", 
            max(table1[Date]))
```

And if you would like to have both, you can add as much columns you want:

```
New_Table = SUMMARIZE(table1,table1[Unique_ID], 
            "Max_Date", max(table1[Date]), 
            "Most_Recent_Mail", 
            CALCULATE(VALUES(table1[mail]), FILTER(all(table1), table1[Date] = max(table1[Date]))))
```

[image]